# Why does Visual Studio do this, and is there a way to stop it?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2012

I am faced with an annoyance in the Visual Studio editor (and this happens with every VS version I can remember using since VS2002).  Maybe I should just suck it up and keep moving, but maybe someone knows something that can soothe my pain.  :-)

In the page editor when working with ASP.NET it likes to rearrange my page code in odd ways.  Well, I want this interference stopped!  A mild example is as follows:

```
EnableClientScript="true">
</asp:RangeValidator>           

<%--                
<br />
<cc1:TimePicker ID="StartTimePicker" runat="server" 
ToolTipText="Choose a time." AccessKey="i" TimeLabelText="* T<u>i</u>me "
```

...is turned into...

```
EnableClientScript="true">
</asp:RangeValidator><%--                
<br />
<cc1:TimePicker ID="StartTimePicker" runat="server" 
ToolTipText="Choose a time." AccessKey="i" TimeLabelText="* T<u>i</u>me "
```

I've seen worse, but this is a typical example.

If it matters, WHY is it doing this?  And even more important, is there some setting somewhere that stops it from doing this kind of thing?  This textual mashing together of elements doesn't affect the page appearance when running, but it make it harder to find things in code using my human eyes.

**Edited to Add:**

After @RouteMapper's tip, I found a place where one can make format setting for HTML formatting:

Tools > Options > Text Editor > HTML > Formating > Tag Specific Options > ASP.NET Controls

Since asp:CustomValidator wasn't in the list, I used New Tag to add it, and then I editing the tag formatting.  In particular I set it to have 2 line breaks after the closing tag.  I thought this would do it.

No, it did not take effect.  Upon building, the code editor crammed the next control back onto it as it had always did.  Quitting VS and restarting didn't help.

Answer (score 1):

Because Microsoft's Visual Studio developers believe they are in sole possession of the One True Code Layout Standard. For "recent editions" of VS (VS 2008+ ?), you can adjust a bunch of editor settings (Tools..Options..Text Editor).

You'll need to fiddle with the settings for the HTML editor and for C#/VB.

I'm with you pal: I care how my code looks and spend time to make it readable for human beings. I don't need my editor "fixing" things for me. It's as bad as Microsoft's justly maligned Clippy. But I digress.

If you drill down, you can adjust the formatting rules for HTML, for CSS and for C# and VB. If you drill down into the HTML options, you can control what happens on a per-tag basis for standard ASP.Net controls as well. The one option you'll probably want to ensure is cleared is the 'Format HTML on paste' checkbox under Tools..Options..Text Editor..HTML..Miscellaneous.

Comment: Sigh.  I figured out the part about the tag formatting, as you can see from my revised question. But VS ignores my settings and does what it pleases.  And the 'Format HTML on paste' checkbox *is* unchecked.

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio will auto-format your code because it makes it pretty. Period.

There are settings that handle it. Here's where you can find those settings for C#:

Tools > Options > Text Editor > C# > Formatting

Comment: Pretty from whose point of view?  I know what prettification is, but in the case it is uglification.  Nevertheless thanks for the tip.

Comment: For the record some people like to use whitespace to make code more 'readable', others despise extra white space, because it interferes with the code 'readability'... IMHO there tends to be a correlation betwen these views and certain learning challenges, like Dyslexia...

Comment: Be that as it may, but when I code something I want the text to *stay the way I coded it*, formatting and all.  Visual Studio treats my C# code text with respect and doesn't screw with it.  That's what I want for my ASP.NET code.

Comment: Pretty from the point of view of leading industry programmers. There are certain standards that the prettification abides by.

Answer (score 0):

When exactly does it affect the formatting ? During editing or when you save/close/reopen the file ?

Are you by any chance pressing the Auto Formatting shortcut key Ctrl + K, Ctrl +D ?

You can change the settings for how Visual Studio formats your document when you press auto format shortcut.

Comment: It makes the change when it does a build.  I've never used the auto formatting feature.